# CSS dropdown menu not working on IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, webkit, gecko

I have a dropdown menu and it's not working with Internet Explorer 10 (and compatibility mode) and Chrome. It does however work with Firefox (latest).

**CSS**:

```
#menu_items
{ float: left;
  width: 600px;
}
  #menu
{ margin:0;
  float: left;
}
#menu li
{ 
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    display: inline;
    background: transparent;
}
#menu li a{
    float: left;
    font: bold 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 24px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
    padding: 16px 0px 10px 40px;
    background: transparent; 
}
#menu li ul li a {
    float: left;
    font: bold 90% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 24px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
    padding: 16px 0px 10px 40px;
    background: transparent; 
}
#menu li:hover ul {
    display: flex;
    float:inherit;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
    padding: 1px 40px 0px 0px;
    background: #669CD8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#90B9E2, #4B75AF);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#90B9E2, #4B75AF);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#90B9E2, #4B75AF);
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#menu li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu li.current a, ul#menu li:hover a
{ 
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
    <div id="menu_items">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="werkwijze.html">Werkwijze</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Producten</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="klimaat.html" id="klimaat">Klimaat</a></li>
                <li><a href="voerbakken.html" id="voerbakken">Voerbakken</a></li>
                <li><a href="voerinstallatie.html" id="voerinstallatie">Voerinstallatie</a></li>
                <li><a href="kraamhokken.html" id="kraamhokken">Kraamhokken</a></li>
                <li><a href="boxen.html" id="boxen">Boxen</a></li>
                <li><a href="bighok.html" id="bighok">Biggen hokken</a></li>
                <li><a href="roosters.html" id="roosters">Roosters</a></li>
                <li><a href="silos.html" id="silos">Silo's</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Some of your CSS syntax are not supported by browsers like chrome and Internet Explorer.. like -moz-linear-gradient etc

Comment: Hence why there is also -o-linear-gradient and -webkit-linear-gradient

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work? I didn't see anything working in FF w/ http://jsfiddle.net/8LaLa/.

Comment: @KatieK hover over 'producten', it works on FF for me... http://i.imgur.com/DC1VM7A.png

Comment: @selten98 - FWIW, nothing appears when hovering over "Producten" in Firefox 21, but new options do appear in FF22.

Comment: @KatieK I use the latest FF on windows 8 and it works on that. So it also doesn't work on older Firefox versions, weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rules for `#menu li:hover ul`, use `display: block;` instead of `display: flex;`.  (See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/8LaLa/1/.)

`display: flex` isn't supported by all browsers - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Your menu may not be clearing properly. You have a lot of floated elements and that can cause errors with your rendering. When you float an element you are taking that element "out of flow". Basically the element will disregard its position in the DOM and try to slide to the side you set in your float. If all child elements inside of a wrapper are floated the parent no longer knows how tall it should be (since all the elements are out of flow) and it sets itself to 0px height or to the height of the tallest in-flow element. To fix this you need a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html). This will tell the browser to make the container clear its children. Hopefully this fixes your issue!